# What is the sample size calculation for a discrete outcome (count variable)?

Tags: sample-size, clinical-trials

What is the sample size calculation for a discrete outcome (count variable)?

For example, I want to design a trial with a placebo and a treatment. The outcome is the number of days of treatment : 14 days for placebo and 10 days for treatment (reduction of 4 days of treatment). Which formula should I use to calculate the sample size for this trial?

I usually use the book "Sample Sizes for Clinical, Laboratory and Epidemiology Studies (Machin et al., 2018)" for sample sizes calculations but I do not find any example for this type of data.

Comment: How do you plan on analyzing your data?

Comment: I plan to use R to analyze the data. I want to see if there is a difference between the placebo ad treatment regarding the number of days of treatment (supposing the treatment is stopped when symptoms disappear).

Comment: Thank you. What test or what model do you plan on using?

Comment: Sample size calculations typically depend on the desired [power of a test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test) against a point alternative hypothesis.  So is the null hypothesis that the placebo time and treatment time are equal? Is the alternative that the mean treatment time is $14-10=4$ fewer than the mean placebo time, or $\frac{10}{14}$ times the mean placebo time, or something else?  What are the assumed distributions of the times under the two hypotheses? What is the significance level you will be using?

Comment: Power (1-beta) is 0.8, alpha is 0.05. The null hypothesis is that placebo and treatment time are equal, the alternative hypothesis is that the mean treatment time is 4 days fewer than the mean placebo time. I don't know the distribution of the time, but I consider it as a discrete variable expressed in days. I wonder if it could be approximated by a continuous distribution.

Comment: You need to make some assumptions about the "distribution of the times," based on your and your colleagues' understanding of the subject matter. If all those on placebo take exactly 14 days and all those on treatment take 10 days, you don't need many cases. If those on placebo can take anywhere between 5 and 20 days, with an average of 14, and those on treatment take anywhere between 3 and 18, with an average of 10, then you need more.